# ListView layouting

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

It looks simple, but it is unbelievable hard.

I want to have such layout:

[image]

It's `ListView` which should take a maximum height of buttons (number of visible buttons is dynamic).

I tried this

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    ...

    <Grid Grid.Row="1">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <StackPanel>
            <Button/>
            <Button/>
            ...
        </StackPanel>

        <ListView Grid.Column="1"/>

    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Problem: `ListView` has a very weird behavior to size self to content. If I add many items, then suddenly it takes all window space.

Question: how to limit `ListView` height to not exceed buttons total height (`StackPanel` height)?

P.S.: mvvm, so pure xaml is preferable.

P.S.S.: I have feeling it will be a binding of something to something. But of what to what?

Comment: put both the buttons and listview in its own panel, and then just worry about aligning left and right?

Comment: @Sayse, why would this helps? What will stop `ListView` from making panel bigger and growing up?

Comment: because you restrict its height to the size of its owner, and then you make sure the panel is fixed in height

Comment: @Sayse, I still don't understand your idea. Note: I don't want to fix size. Layout should be dynamic (normal/maximized window of any size). Number of visible buttons will vary -> `StackPanel` height will vary -> `ListView` should take only that height, not more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to data bind the `ActualHeight` of your `StackPanel` to the `ListView.Height` so that the `ListView` won't grow larger than the `Button`'s `StackPanel`:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid Grid.Row="1">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Name="ButtonPanel" Grid.Column="0">
            <Button Content="Click" />
            <Button Content="Click" />
            <Button Content="Click" />
        </StackPanel>
        <ListView Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Tests}" 
            Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=ButtonPanel}" />
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: You saved me again! Thanks. (and yes, I feel ashamed for not being able to solve such problem alone yet)

Comment: We live and learn. That would have stumped me too at some point in the past. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can bind the `MaxHeight` property of your lower content grid to the `ActualHeight` of the buttons `StackPanel`. Futher more, you need to set the `VerticalAlignment` of the buttons panel to `Bottom`.

This way, you can add more parts in vertically, but still stick to the buttons panel height.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    ...

    <Grid Grid.Row="1"
          MaxHeight="{Binding ElementName=ButtonPanel, Path=ActualHeight}">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <StackPanel Name="ButtonPanel"
                    VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
            <Button Content="Button"/>
            <Button Content="Button"/>
            <Button Content="Button"/>
        </StackPanel>

        <ListView Grid.Column="1"/>

        <!-- Multiple controls can be added here,
             but the lower part will still stick
             to the size of the buttons panel -->
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: That also works, thanks. But it's more *shady* (less obvious) than @Sheridan's solution.